# python - issue while calling a function while using conditionality in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two functions and I am calling each of them as shown in my "simplified" codes

```
def simpleFunction(a,b,c=10):
    y = a+b+c if a<2 else b+c
    return y

def simpleFunction2(a,b,c=10):
    y = a+b+c
    return y

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,(10,3)),columns=['A','B','C'])
```

when I run

```
df['D'] = np.where(df['A']>5,simpleFunction2(df['A'],df['C'],df['B']),0)
```

It runs fine and adds another column D with values

but when I run

```
df['D'] = np.where(df['A']>5,simpleFunction(df['A'],df['C'],df['B']),0)
```

I get an error

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

How do I make it work?

Comment: Replace `if/else` with `np.where` in your `simpleFunction`.

Comment: perfect! that did work! thanks again @Psidom